# Save PDF in CMYK colour profile

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, cmyk, cgpdfcontext

I have an iOS app written in Swift, where you can create images with texts etc. In the end, you can create a PDF, which is destined for printing. I've got a response from the printing house that it has to be in 300 DPI, which I've fixed, but they also require CMYK colour profile.

I've only found this post:
[Include ICC Colour Profile in PDF created with Objective-C iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163537/include-icc-colour-profile-in-pdf-created-with-objective-c-ios)

and the author states it's impossible. Also, this is stated in Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2313/_index.html

> These contexts let you specify a CGColorSpace:
>
> CGBitmapContext CGWindowContext And these do not:
>
> CGPDFContext CGPostScriptContext

But I cannot believe there isn't any other way. Even if it's not possible using pdfContext, there must be other API to do so. I've found other PDF-making libraries on github, but I haven't found any information in terms of colour profile support.

Comment: @Maria: The backticks are for `code`, not for arbitrary emphasis. “iOS”, “API”, “Swift” etc are not code, or keywords in the Swift language.

Comment: You are referring very old doc please check latest printer doc I think its feasible with latest update.

Comment: Sorry :) It just looked cleaner. Please focus on the question itself :)

Comment: @CodeChanger can you please provide a link to that doc?

Comment: Are you sending this PDF back to your own server before sending to your printer? If so I would recommend converting it there. GhostScript is one tool which I have seen used at printing companies before.

Comment: I create PDF file and share it via email. External server seems interesting, but I'd say it's a last resort.